# Database column(s) that relate to one of multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I feel this is a very basic question, still I cant figure out a good way of doing it even though I've worked quite a bit with databases. Also can't seem to find anything when googling for it.

Let's say I have a bunch of tables, each describing a type of item.

For instance:

```
Table candles:
id█  name  █length█diameter▌burntime▌
▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▌
1 █ candle1█54    █  6     █  180   ▌
69█ candle2█29    █  16    █  145   ▌
80█ candle3█100   █ 40     █  110   ▌


Table coasters:
id█  name  █thickness█diameter▌color   ▌
▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▌
1 █coaster1█5        █  20    █#ffffff ▌
6 █coaster2█8        █  41    █#ff0051 ▌
8 █coaster3█7        █ 38     █#002199 ▌


Table baskets:
id█  name  █size█
▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀█
1 █basket1 █5   █
2 █basket2 █8   █
3 █basket3 █22  █
```

Now I have another table. Let's call it shoppingcarts. Each record in this table needs to hold an array of these items. This is where I don't know how to proceed.
So I need a many to many relationship, which means I need a junction/pivot-table.
But how?

Should I have one junction-table for each type of item? With a foreign key for cart-id and one for the record-id for candle/coaster/etc.
Then when listing the content of the cart I need to check every single junction-table, one for each type of item. Doesn't sound very clean to me.

Or should I only have one single junction-table, which has a column for table-name and one for record-id?
Seems very dirty too.

I suppose there's a much better way of doing this, but I can't think of it.
How should this be done?

Comment: _Or should I onnly have one single junction-table, which has a column for table-name and one for record-id?_ Yes, a perfect solution, if you already have all these tables! What don't you like about it?

Comment: If you are going to have a 'shoppingcart' table, then you need to distinguish between items as products, where they have a quantity, price, etc, and their product detail, which is what you have above. So maybe consider something like a product table that links back to the individual detail, but also stores quantity in stock, price etc. The main weakness with your model at the moment is that a new product type requires a whole new table. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125029/design-a-database-for-a-shopping-cart-application for example.

Comment: Actually, even better solution would be having the current stuff stored in two tables, something like `goods` (id, name) and `goods-properties` (id, goodsId, property, value), where "property" will be e.g. `size` and value will be e.g. `5` (for basket 1)

Comment: You should keep all products in single table with their attribute, in 2nd table you should keep their stock, and you should keep your orders in another table..all tables should be linked with each other via foreign keys....

Comment: @TomasPastircak Your first comment.. To me it feels very unclean to let every junction-record have a (varchar?-)field for a table-name, rather than having a nice 32 bit integer id as I'm used to. And it's not possible to add indexed foreign keys for any of these then?

Comment: Okay, having a shopping cart as example might not have been the best. I simply want to know a good way of having a container hold different types of items.
@ZafarMalik Yes, that does make it easy and efficient.. But the properties of these types of items might differ a lot.. As in my example in the question. How should those be listed? Still a new column for every new property? That means coaster would have a possible value for i.e. burntime, which doesn't really make sense. Each record would take up much more space, holding null for a bunch of columns they'll never use.

Comment: Or should I have a properties-colun with a type of varchar, listing properties in the form of json or such? That makes querying for those properties i.e. search for baskets with sizes with 10 or greater very hard and inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

One potential way of tackling this problem is to think about the items you have as objects, then think about how you might model these relationally. If you treat all of your items as objects, with properties, that have values, then this is a common schema for storing this information.

This is often referred to as [O/R Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

A simple relational example might look like:

Object - defines all of your items

```
+----+----------+---------+
| Id |   Name   |  Type   |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 | Candle1  | Candle  |
|  2 | Coaster1 | Coaster |
|  3 | Basket1  | Basket  |
+----+----------+---------+
```

ObjectProperty - defines all of your properties

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| Id |   Name    | DataType |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Length    | Float    |
|  2 | Diameter  | Float    |
|  3 | Burntime  | Float    |
|  4 | Thickness | Float    |
|  5 | Color     | String   |
|  6 | Size      | Int      |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

ObjectPropertyValue - defines the relationships between objects and properties, and the values

```
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| Id | ObjectId | PropertyId | ValueInt | ValueFloat | ValueDate | ValueString |
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|  1 |        1 |          1 | NULL     | 54.0       | NULL      | NULL        |
|  2 |        1 |          2 | NULL     | 29.0       | NULL      | NULL        |
|  3 |        3 |          6 | 5        | NULL       | NULL      | NULL        |
+----+----------+------------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

To retrieve all of the values for a single object, you can run a query like:

```
SELECT          OP.Name,
                OP.DataType,
                OPV.ValueInt,
                OPV.ValueFloat,
                OPV.ValueDate,
                OPV.ValueString

FROM            ObjectProperty OP
INNER JOIN      ObjectPropertyValue OPV ON OP.Id = OPV.PropertyId

WHERE           OPV.ObjectId = 1
```

There are several advantages to storing information in this format:

- It's extensible so you don't need a new table every time a new object
  type comes along
- You can have as many properties as you need per
  object
- Typing the property values means you can still do relevant queries
  based on data types

i.e. To search for all candles with a length less than 50:

```
SELECT      O.Id, 
            O.Name,
            OP.Name,
            OPV.ValueFloat 
FROM        Object O
INNER JOIN  ObjectPropertyValue OPV ON O.Id = OPV.ObjectId
INNER JOIN  OpjectProperty OP ON OPV.PropertyId = OP.Id

WHERE       OP.Name = 'Length'
AND         O.Type = 'Candle'
AND         OPV.ValueFloat <= 50.0;
```

However, there are also disadvantages:

- It's hard to build queries on the fly without dynamic sql because you first need to know what kind of properties you are looking for on particular objects, and then choose the appropriate columns to search on in ObjectPropertyValue
- Squeezing objects into generic structures can sometimes make very simple operations quite complex. Compare how easy it would be to get the candles in your table structure vs the query above for example.

There are other disadvantages too, but a good place to start reading about this subject in detail is [O/R Mapping and Relational Data](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html)

Finally, an alternative solution for solving this problem is the concept of [NoSQL, an alternative mechanism to storing objects relationally.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL)

Jeff Atwood also has a [great article](http://blog.codinghorror.com/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science/) on this very subject.